# BST to Double-LinkedList Algorithm complexity?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am looking at the code to do this in CC150. One of its method is as follows, it does this by retrieving the tail of the left sub-tree.

```
public static BiNode convert(BiNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }

    BiNode part1 = convert(root.node1);
    BiNode part2 = convert(root.node2);

    if (part1 != null) {
        concat(getTail(part1), root);
    }

    if (part2 != null) {
        concat(root, part2);
    }

    return part1 == null ? root : part1;
}   

public static BiNode getTail(BiNode node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    while (node.node2 != null) {
        node = node.node2;
    }
    return node;
}

public static void concat(BiNode x, BiNode y) {
    x.node2 = y;
    y.node1 = x;
}

public class BiNode {
    public BiNode node1;
    public BiNode node2;
    public int data; 
    public BiNode(int d) {
        data = d;
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is the Time Complexity the author gives in the book **O(n^2)**. What I came up with is **T(N) = 2*T(N/2) + O(N/2), O(N/2) is consumed by the getting tail reference because it needs to traverse a list length of O(N/2).** So by Master Theorem, it should be O(NlogN). Did I do anything wrong? Thank you!

Comment: If I'm reading this right then half the nodes will have to traverse up to n/2 nodes in `getTail`. That would give `(n/2)*(n/2)`, which is `(n^2)/4`, meaning O(n^2).

Comment: Hi Jim. Thank you for your answer, but I don't think you are right. The root has to traverse n/2 nodes, the node in level two will only have to traverse n/4 node,..., so I think only the root has to traverse up to n/2 nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static BiNode convert(BiNode root) {//worst case BST everything
    if (root == null) {                    // on left branch (node1)
        return null;
    }

    BiNode part1 = convert(root.node1);//Called n times
    BiNode part2 = convert(root.node2);//Single call at beginning

    if (part1 != null) {
        concat(getTail(part1), root);// O(n) every recursive call
    }                                // for worst case so 1 to n
                                     // SEE BELOW
    if (part2 != null) {            
        concat(root, part2);
    }

    return part1 == null ? root : part1;
}   

public static BiNode getTail(BiNode node) {//O(n)
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    while (node.node2 != null) {
        node = node.node2;
    }
    return node;
}

public static void concat(BiNode x, BiNode y) {//O(1)
    x.node2 = y;
    y.node1 = x;
}
```

```
SAMPLE TREE:
          4
         /
        3
       /
      2
     /
    1
```

As you can see, in the worst case scenario (Big-Oh is not average case), the BST would be structured using only the node1 branch(es). Thus, the recursion would have a have to run getTail() with '1 + 2 + ... +  N' problem sizes to complete the conversion.

[image]

Which is O(n^2)

Comment: Thank you. But I think the author means the average time by O(n^2).